# Use FillLayout with Browser in SWT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a view that consists of a heading and a browser. I want the browser to fill my view. This is how it should look:
[image]

I have tried out different combinations.

```
    c = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    c.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    Label l = new Label(c, SWT.NONE);
    l.setBackground(color);
    l.setText("----------------------Heading--------------------------------");
    l.setFont(new Font(null, new FontData(Constants.FONT, 12, SWT.BOLD)));

    Composite wrapper = new Composite(c, SWT.NONE);
    wrapper.setBackground(new Color(null, 0, 0, 0));
    wrapper.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    browser = new Browser(wrapper, SWT.WRAP);
    browser.setBackground(color);
```

produces:
[image]

Setting a FillLayout to `c` does not work either. By doing so both, heading and browser, share the view's size and have an equal size.

```
    c = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    c.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    Label l = new Label(c, SWT.NONE);
    l.setBackground(color);
    l.setText("----------------------Heading--------------------------------");
    l.setFont(new Font(null, new FontData(Constants.FONT, 12, SWT.BOLD)));

    browser = new Browser(c, SWT.WRAP);
    browser.setBackground(color);
```

produces:
[image]

I have also tried the following:

```
composite with filllayout

-> composite with gridlayout

    ->composite with rowLayout (fixed height, grab right)

    ->composite with rowLayout

        -> composite with fillLayout

            -> composite with browser
```

Comment: At minimum, `Composite c` has no *layoutdata* for its parent to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the header and browser have the same parent, you could use a `GridLayout` like this:

```java
parent.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );
label.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false ) );
browser.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ) );
```

Even though a one-cell-grid isn't really what a GridLayout is meant for, it should do the trick. The layout data advise the label to align at the top and use all horizontal space and the browser to use the horizontal and vertical space